# Changing RecyclerView Items on a button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want a certain layout to become visible on all my recyclerview items when a button on the actionbar is clicked.

Google didn't help, and I have no idea how to go about this.

An example of this would be when a user wants to delete a lot of SMS messages from the inbox and press-and-hold suddenly enables checkboxes on every item in the recyclerview.

EDIT:

```
public class ViewCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewCartAdapter.DataViewHolder>
{
    private List<ViewCartModel.Product> dataList;
    private Context con;

    public ViewCartAdapter(Context context, List<ViewCartModel.Product> list)
    {
        this.dataList = list;
        con = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder dataViewHolder, int i)
    {
        dataViewHolder.setClickListener(new DataViewHolder.ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, int pos, boolean isLongClick)
            {

            }
        });

        ViewCartModel.Product item = dataList.get(i);

        Picasso.with(con).load(item.getThumb().replaceAll(" ", "%20")).into(dataViewHolder.itemImage);
        dataViewHolder.itemName.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getName().toUpperCase()).toString());
        dataViewHolder.itemPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        dataViewHolder.categoryID = item.getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tile_cart, viewGroup, false);
        DataViewHolder dvh = new DataViewHolder(itemView);

        return dvh;
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        protected ImageView itemImage;
        protected TextView itemName;
        protected TextView itemPrice;
        protected String categoryID;

        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public DataViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);

            itemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            itemPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
            itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public interface ClickListener
        {
            /**
             * Called when the view is clicked.
             *
             * @param v           view that is clicked
             * @param position    of the clicked item
             * @param isLongClick true if long click, false otherwise
             */

            public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);
        }

        public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener)
        {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), false); // here, get position
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show related part of code

Comment: You want me to post my Adapter code? Sure. Doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a boolean telling if the checkboxes are shown or hidden, using its value when binding to the ViewHolder. Then when your button is long pressed, toggle the value of the boolean, and call "notifyItemRangeChanged" on the adapter to rebind the ViewHolder.